# Content-type ignored

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

this is my first question to the community, although I usually find all the answers I need on the forum, I had no luck on this one.

The problem is I have a php script witch outputs an inline pdf like so:

```
$doc = base64_decode( $rapport );

header('Content-type: application/pdf');

header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='rapport.pdf'");

echo $doc;
```

But it only works when i open the page as an admin on my wordpress site.

If another user opens it, the Content-type header just get ignored ... but i can see the bytes of the doc.

I tested myself by opening the same page in the same browser logged in as another user and the header I see in chrome dev-tool is Text while it is application/pdf normally.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thx!

**Edit**: Problem half solved, the wp super cache plugin was compressing the output so everything works fine again without the cache... Any suggestions as how I should set the cache plugin to avoid breaking the dynamic content?